# Cyrillic symbols in Linux file names

Tags: linux, shell, locale

I have a Linux, made by Buildroot tool.

And I faced with a problem with creating files with cyrillic names. When I try to create a file, for example with such command:

```
touch файл.txt
```

I get a file, named like `????.txt`.

I tried to export `LANG` variable:

```
# export LANG=ru_RU.utf8
# echo $LANG
ru_RU.utf8
```

And I also tried to create the file in `/temp` directory and at an EXT3 partition, but the result is the same.

In general, I can use cyrillic in the system: programs can print them, and I can use cyrillic symbols in programs (like in vi, for example).

What else can I try to do?

Comment: Do you have `ru_RU.utf8` in the `locale -a` list? If not, do you have any other `.utf8` locale at all? (It doesn't need to be ru_RU as long as it's UTF-8.)

Comment: Are you sure the actual name created is ???? or might it be the tool you’re using?

Answer (score 1):

`touch` *did* create the file name correctly. But `ls` is not displaying it. That's because `ls` by default displays question marks for anything that is doesn't recognize as a printable character.

You can test this by using another command to display the contents of the directory. Try any of the following commands:

```
$ ls --show-control-chars
$ sh -c 'echo *'
$ python3 -c 'import os; print(os.listdir("."))'
```

Setting $LANG to a UTF-8 locale, as you did when you typed `export LANG=ru_RU.UTF-8`, should have fixed the problem. Since that didn't work, check

- If `LC_CTYPE` has been set, it will override the value of `LANG`.
- Has your system be installed with Russian-language support? If not, use another supported locale such as `en_US.UTF-8`.